# NTFS Permissions

Tags: permissions, ntfs

I'm running ubuntu 13.10 x86_64 and I have modified `/etc/fstab` to mount my NTFS HDD with permissions but I'm getting some permissions errors because the owner is "root" instead of my user.

Thanks in advance

P.S: I had no problems doing this in Ubuntu 13.04 32bits

EDIT:

fstab content:

```
#/etc/fstab: static file system information.

#Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
#device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
#that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).

#<file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
#/ was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=3e857b61-2d2b-469a-a3eb-de1cf4d5130a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       
#/home was on /dev/sda7 during installation
#UUID=14887804-6799-443e-955f-6b2872cd441a /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
#swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
#UUID=2da59282-61ee-40d2-821b-2042ff556748 none            swap    sw              0       0
#UUID=4A1499C11499B085 /media/ivykoko/269Gb ntfs umask=0000,utf8 0 0
```

Comment: Please post `/etc/fstab` content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mount the drive with your user as the owner add the `uid` option.

Type `id` in the terminal to get your user ID from the output: `uid=####`.

Then add that option to fstab so your new entry will look like:

`UUID=4A1499C11499B085 /media/ivykoko/269Gb ntfs umask=0000,utf8,uid=#### 0 0`

Where #### is your actual uid.

Then unmount and remount the drive.